# Git: Copy folder from master to the root of another branch

Tags: git, github, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have a static website which is generating an `output` folder to the `MyBlog/output` in the `master` branch. But I want output to be the source of my GH Pages, I am looking for a way to use `output` as the root of `gh-pages` branch.

That's my `deploy.yml`

```yaml
name: Deploy Site
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
      with:
        submodules: recursive
    - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '3.1.100'
    - run: dotnet run --project "MyBlog" -- deploy
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    - run: git push
```

What should I do / add to my deploy.yml to do what I want please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: [Checkout a different branch](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-a-different-branch) ?

Comment: I've edited and added a question

Comment: @Joe, yes but I want `output` to be the root of my other branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this should work. Remove the last line `- run: git push` from your action. Then add the following.

```
- name: Deploy
  uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
  with:
    github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    publish_dir: ./MyBlog/output
```

Finally your `deploy.yml` should be:

```
name: Deploy Site
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
      with:
        submodules: recursive
    - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '3.1.100'
    - run: dotnet run --project "MyBlog" -- deploy
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    - name: Deploy
      uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        publish_dir: ./MyBlog/output
```

I am assuming that `MyBlog` is a folder present at root. Then this action will put the contents of your `output` folder into the `gh-pages` branch directly. I hope this is what you wanted to achieve.

In case you wish to know more, you can visit [this](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages#%EF%B8%8F-source-directory-publish_dir)